# How can I upload file in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Upload file in Liferay

can any one help me How can i upload my file in document and media folder using DLFileEntry
I search but didn't get exact code. How can i do this. 
I just put my file controller in jsp file.
I tries using following code

```
UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);

String sourceFileName = uploadRequest.getFileName("fileName");
System.out.println("file name  " + sourceFileName);

File file = uploadRequest.getFile("fileName");
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
System.out.println("User Id " + themeDisplay.getUserId() + ": " + themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId());
long FOLDER_ID = 0;
long repositoryId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
long parentFolderId = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID;
List<Folder> lFolder = DLAppServiceUtil.getFolders(repositoryId, parentFolderId);
for (Folder folder : lFolder) {
    System.out.println(lFolder);
    System.out.println(folder.getFolderId());
}

//ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(actionRequest);
ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(FileEntry.class.getName(), actionRequest);
System.out.println("hello");
long defaultRepoId = DLFolderConstants.getDataRepositoryId(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(),DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID);

DLFileEntry dlFileEntry=DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(themeDisplay.getUserId(),themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), defaultRepoId, 12518, sourceFileName, MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file), "fileTitle", "fileDesc", "sss",0,null,file,null,file.length(),serviceContext);

DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(themeDisplay.getUserId(), dlFileEntry.getFileEntryId(), sourceFileName, MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file), "fileTitle", "fileDesc", "comment", true, dlFileEntry.getFileEntryTypeId(), null,file, null, file.length(), serviceContext);
```

But didn't get success.

Can any one copy paste code here please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide code which you have tried ?

Comment: Does the folder `Uploads` exist? If you haven't already created that folder by the time this code executes, you'll have errors.

Comment: yes that is exists. but i update my code see..

Comment: Using both the code provided prior to the edit (ensuring the sub folder existed), and the newly added source, I am not having an issue uploading the file. I must emphasize that I did not *just put my file controller in jsp file.* Move the source to an actual action method and continue your efforts there.

Comment: I can upload my file only once. second time it gives me error Request failed

Comment: Assuming this is due to `duplicate` file exception, make the `file title` unique.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone stumbles across this:

upload_file.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<portlet:actionURL name='uploadFile' var="uploadFileURL" windowState="normal" />

<aui:form action="<%= uploadFileURL %>" method="POST" name="fm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <aui:fieldset>

    <aui:input type="file" name="file-to-upload"/>

    <aui:button-row>
      <aui:button type="submit" />
    </aui:button-row>

  </aui:fieldset>
</aui:form>
```

MyPortlet.java:

```
public class MyPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

//action method
public void uploadFile(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest 
        = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(request);

    ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(
            MyPortlet.class.getName(), uploadRequest);

    this.uploadFileEntity(serviceContext, uploadRequest);

    response.setRenderParameter("mvcPath", "/html/view.jsp");
}

// Create a folder called "A_FOLDER" in Documents & Media
private void uploadFileEntity(ServiceContext serviceContext, 
        UploadPortletRequest request) 
                throws PortalException, SystemException {

    String filename = "";
    String description = "File description";

    try{

        // serviceContext.scopeGroupId is the groupId of a site
        long repositoryId = DLFolderConstants.getDataRepositoryId(
            serviceContext.getScopeGroupId(), 
            DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID);


        Folder f = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(
            repositoryId, 0L, "A_FOLDER");
        long folderId = f.getFolderId();


        File file = request.getFile("file-to-upload");
        filename = request.getFileName("file-to-upload");
        String mimeType =  MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file);

        FileEntry entry = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(serviceContext.getUserId(), 
                repositoryId, folderId, filename, 
                mimeType, filename, description, "", 
                file, serviceContext
        );  

    }catch(PortalException e){
        _log.error("An exception occured uploading file: " 
                + e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }catch(SystemException e ){
        _log.error("An exception occured uploading file: " 
                + e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}

private static Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(MyPortlet.class);
}
```