# Can you save the value of a input type=file in a java variable?

Tags: java, liferay

I've been trying to do this in a liferay module project. By making an input type=file in my view.jsp and saving it in a java File variable but i can't get it to work. Is this possible? and if yes, how?

So far i've looked for a paramutil method that i can use but there don't seem to be any. And i've tried to use request.getParameter but this doesn't allow for the type File to be used. After that I tried to create a upload request and fill it with the data from the form. But this also didn't work for me.

I wanted to make a form in my jsp file and let people upload a file via the input and let my java code run on submit to add the file to the documentlibrary.

Answer (score 0):

A java File (as in `java.io.File`) is an abstraction for a pointer to something sitting on your file system. When you upload data in a portlet or any other means in a web application, you're first dealing with a stream of data that usually has no representation on the hard drive (unless you explicitly store it there). Thus, `ParamUtil` will not reveal anything of type `File`, because that's - by definition - not part of a http request.

There is a lot of upload sample code, that you might need to adapt to the version you're running ([for example this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27518094/13447)) - but you'll first need to understand that you're not looking for any representation of data on your hard drive.